# timelinejson.html:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token @ in JSON at position 1296

Tags: javascript, html, json

I am new to JSON. I need to pass JSON data through a HTML page using the code below but it is not displaying the data in HTML page. It is giving me error when I debug...

timelinejson.html:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token @ in JSON at position 1296

Please help. Thank you for your precious time.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>   
<html>
<head>
<style>

table, th , td  {
border-top: 1px solid purple;
border-collapse: collapse;
padding: 5px;

}
table tr:nth-child(odd) {
background-color: #f1f1f1;

}
table tr:nth-child(even) {
background-color: #ffffff;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="time"></div>

<script>
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "http://outpaceng.com/linejson.php";

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
    myFunction(xmlhttp.responseText);
      }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
xmlhttp.send();

function myFunction(response) {
var arr = JSON.parse(response);
var i;
     var out = "<table>";  

for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    out += "<tr><td>" +
    arr[i].Firstname +
    "</td><td>" +
    arr[i].Lastname +
    "</td><td>" +
    arr[i].Username +
    "</td><td>" +
    arr[i].Post +
    "</td><td>" +
    arr[i].Post_date +
    "</td></tr>";
    }
     out += "</table>";
document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = out;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check if the json is valid using a json validator

i suggest the following

```
for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    out += "<tr><td>" +
    arr[i].Firstname +
    "</td><td>" +
    arr[i].Lastname +
    "</td><td>" +
    arr[i].Username +
    "</td><td>" +
    arr[i].Post +
    "</td><td>" +
    arr[i].Post_date +
    "</td></tr>";
    }


}
 out += "</table>";//move outside of loop
document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = out;//move outside of loop
```

Comment: Thank you so very much...I got the error from the json validator.

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON isn't valid !
Try to fix that, and it will work ;)

You can verify it at http://jsonlint.com/

[image]

Answer (score 0):

well, your code is correct! but your JSON file is wrongly structured.